# C++ passing argument of "struct" type as reference (&) or passing it by value

Tags: c++, struct

I have the following function in C++:

```
Family whoAmI(Family myFam,string MyName, int MyAge)
{
    myFam.Name = MyName;
    myFam.Age = MyAge;
    return myFam;
}
```

It returns a `struct` of this type:

```
struct Family
{
    string Name;
    int Age;
};
```

My question is that: I want my function to return a specific kind of `struct` which in our example is `Family`, but in order to specify the return type of the function, I have to declare the struct first, and cast it as the return type of function, like this: `Family whoAmI() {..}`. Then I have to add values in the function to a `struct` which ends up being similar to `Family`. This means that I need to re-declare a similar `struct` in the function itself (which is quite memory consuming). What I did was to pass a reference of `struct` to the function to prevent a duplication of `struct` in the function. Now, is this correct? Since it occupies a place in arguments and thus making it less convenient.

Now, I call it like this:

```
Family x;
Family result = whoAmI(x, "Mostafa", 25);
```

Comment: Why not just make this a constructor of `Family` ?

Comment: Your code looks like you are looking for a constructor.

Comment: can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a constructor.

```
struct Family {
  Family(const std::string& Name, int Age) 
    : Name(Name), Age(Age) {}

  std::string Name;
  int Age;
};

// use like:
Family me{"AName", 45}; // or Family me("AName", 45); on old compilers
```

Comment: very good. thanks. Can I ask why you have declared `std:string&` as `const`?

Comment: @MostafaTalebi The argument is a reference to a constant object. Constant since you are not going to modify it, reference since this avoid a copy.